# RAID 5 configuration with two drives

Tags: sql-server, raid

I am new into RAID implementation. I have researched on RAID and learned about RAID levels.

I have to install SQL Server into one of the server(server have two drives currently). I am told by Application team to implement RAID 5 with approximately 800 GB and there should be an OS, SQL Server, backup and Log drive arrays.

As far I know, with two drives I can configure either RAID 0 or RAID 1.

Any suggestion on how I can implement this?

**Additional info**

I have two drives now:

- C Drive: 750 GB
- D Drive: 8.00 TB

Comment: RAID-5 requires at least 3 disks, so "RAID-5" and 2 disks in the same constraint bag are mutually excluding each other.

Comment: So should i partition one disk,say D drive into two and then go on with RAID 5 ?

Comment: "So should i partition one disk"  No.  That would be bad.  Are you sure your 8TB "drive" is really a single disk?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by single disk.?I know that the server is brand new with new OS installation.

Comment: It's a physical server? With two physical disks?

Comment: @David I understand you question now.Yeah it is a physical server ,but i don't know whether it is a single disk.How can i check that.?I checked in device manager and i can see two `DELL PERC H730 Mini SCSI Disk Device` listed under Disk drives.

Comment: Let us say it again: RAID-5 requires at least 3 **physical** disks. Creating 2 partitions on a physical disk does not create 2 physical disks, so you gain nothing there. If your C and D are physical disks, you have two of them, RAID-5 requires 3, end of story.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i understand.I have less knowledge when it comes to hardware and RAID concept is new to me as well.

Comment: We are drifting away from databases issues, so this becomes offtopic. Also can't your "Application team" help you, since they are the one insisting on RAID-5 (for whatever reasons, this is not exactly the most loved configuration anymore; see RAID 5 and RAID 6 entries on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID)?

Comment: Dell PERC is a hardware RAID controller (it stands for PowerEdge RAID Controller). In combination with your statement about the 8TB drive D: it's safe to assume that you already have some sort of a RAID device mapped to D: -- use the storage management GUI that should be included with PERC to view its configuration and possibly  redefine it according to what's requested.

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestion on how I can implement this?
>   I can see two DELL PERC H730 Mini SCSI Disk Device

The [DELL PERC H730](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H730P.pdf) is a RAID controller, and is responsible for the RAID configuration for your server.  Once it configures disks in a RAID configuration, it presents each RAID set as a single Disk to Windows.

You'll need to figure out how to configure that controller, or ask for help from someone who can.

Comment: Browne : If its a RAID controller why is it showing two ?or disks are mounted on the RAID controller?

Comment: You can delete your own comments (maybe you want to delete the first two?).

Answer (score 0):

### tl:dr

> The SAME (Stripe And Mirror Everything - meaning RAID 1+0) configuration 
>   produces close to optimal performance for ALL workloads (Juan Loiaza - Oracle database chief architect)

Sophisticated hybid solutions are not dealt with here (see below).

### Introduction:

Anytime someone says to me that their organisation is implementing a database storage system using RAID 5, I just shake my head in pity and sadness and say "I hope you have a lot of time to spend listening to your users complaining about poor performance!".

RAID 5 is (IMHO - see below) a false economy, penny-pinching solution to storage.  It ends up being far more costly in terms of wasted time and resources in the long run. This is despite the fact that it is initially cheaper than RAID 10 (which is what one should use for databases in a production environment).

The following is copied from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/949/306260):

> Let's say you have a 6 drive array and your drives can do 100 I/Os per
>   second (IOPS). If you have 100% reads, all six drives will be used and
>   you'll have about 600 IOPS for both RAID 10 and RAID 5.
>
> The worst case scenario is 100% writes. In that scenario, RAID 10's
>   performance will be cut in half (since each write goes to two drives),
>   so it will get 300 IOPS. RAID-5 will convert each write into two reads
>   followed by two writes, so it will get 1/4 the performance or about
>   150 IOPS. That's a pretty big hit.
>
> Your actual read/write pattern will be somewhere in-between these two
>   extremes, but this is why RAID 10 is usually recommended for databases.

i.e very poor write performance (corresponds to my personal experience with RAID 5)

That guy seems to know what he's talking about, however I have no idea who he is. Let's see what some well-known experts have to say, Juan Loaiza (Oracle database's chief architect - so you might expect him to know a thing or two about databases and disk arrays - paper available on baarf.dk - see below) says:

> Storage configuration does not have to be this complicated.
>
> A simple, efficient, and highly available storage configuration is
>   possible. The basic idea of this configuration is to make extensive
>   use of striping across large sets of disks using a methodology that we
>   will describe later. To achieve high availability the disks should be
>   mirrored. We call this methodology S.A.M.E. SAME stands for Stripe and
>   Mirror Everything.

This is **NOT** RAID 5 (which has parity bits, which are costly) - in fact it means RAID 10 (or 1+0).

From  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID):

> RAID 1+0: (see: RAID 10) creates a striped set from a series of
>   mirrored drives. The array can sustain multiple drive losses so long
>   as no mirror loses all its drives

(another quote from the Loaiza paper):

> The SAME configuration produces close to optimal performance for ALL 
>   workloads:

The quote continues:

> OLTP, Warehouse, and Batch. We believe that the SAME
>   configuration will become the predominant configuration for Oracle
>   databases. Oracle is working with leading storage vendors to optimize
>   and automate this methodology

So, Oracle wants to implement **automatic** RAID 1+0!

From [here](https://www.hdd-tool.com/raid/raid-10-as-raid-01.html#.WvK07nXwY_M):

> RAID 10 provides better fault resilience and “rebuild” performance
>   than RAID 01. Both array types provide very good to excellent overall
>   performance by combining the speed of RAID 0 with the redundancy of
>   RAID 1 without requiring parity calculations.

From [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/raid10-vs-raid01):

> RAID 10 fault tolerance is more. On RAID 10, since there are many
>   groups (as the individual group is only two disks), even if three
>   disks fails (one in each group), the RAID 10 is still functional. In
>   the above RAID 10 example, even if Disk 1, Disk 3, Disk 5 fails, the
>   RAID 10 will still be functional. So, given a choice between RAID 10
>   and RAID 01, always choose RAID 10.

From [here](https://serverfault.com/a/145326/306260) (a guy with a 60K rep!):

> Unless your circumstances are exceptional, you should never use 0+1.

From [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) (the [Canonical question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) on ServerFault! Appears to be the same guy as the above quote)

> RAID 01
>
> It provides no additional speed over RAID 10, but substantially less
>   redundancy and should be avoided at all costs.

[Kevin Kline](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=kevin%20kline) author of [SQL in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518846) wrote here (in [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41949/34007)):

> was surprised that in a write-heavy scenario RAID5 was over 3x slower
>   than RAID10 (it was 319% slower, to be specific). Your mileage may
>   vary according to the actual ratio of reads versus writes in your
>   scenarios.

Finally, on a humourous note, take a quick look here at [baarf.dk](http://www.baarf.dk/) (site in English) - it's the "Battle Against Any Raid F" (F = four/five and others).

Take a look at the paper by Cary Millsap concerning the **real** economics of RAID 5. The word "barf" in English means to get sick - I don't think the acronym was chosen by accident! :-) Seriously, there are good papers on this site (see Juan Loaiza above) and the people behind it are all serious Oracle practictioners although the "organisation" per se appears defunct.

## Summing up:

Now, there are many people recommending hybrid configurations out there (logs on RAID X, data on RAID Y, OS on RAID Z, Server software itself on ZFS, something else on SSD... the list goes on (and on...). Don't get me wrong, I'm not knocking those who make these recommendations and I don't have time or expertise to check them all out (i.e. read benchmarks by people whose reps I trust), but it's worth remembering what Juan Loaiza wrote:

> The SAME configuration produces close to optimal performance for ALL
>   workloads

Having said all of the above, I wouldn't put the OS or server software (upgrades and the like) on the same disks as my data and I would separate my data from my  WAL/Redo/Undo.

RAID 5 is meant to be good for read heavy workloads - why not just use the file system plus vi or possibly Git as your database server? :-)

Finally, remember that for **really serious** systems, you need to have a disk array which supports hot-pluggable spares.